# is it possible to change block' gas limit?

Tags: remix, ropsten, gas-limit, blocks, out-of-gas

I'm trying to execute some heavy transactions. Before execute it, Remix advises me about the gas limit:

[image]

Ok, then I change my gas limit on Metamask to 9,000,000 (I'm on Ropsten network):

[image]

And finally, when I'm gonna execute it, I got this error about block' gas limit:

[image]

So... I'm not sure if there's a solution to this, because I'm thinking that if the block hasn't created, then nobody knows its gas limit, right? Is there another solution available to execute some heavy transactions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the transaction will not just fail? When estimating gas, this error can occur if the transaction will always be reverted.

Comment: Yes, the T will fail eventually due to gas limit. I tried the same T but with less information (size of data structures, less loop' iterations, etc.) and it worked.

Comment: In that case, you may be able to up the gas limit if you're running your own local network (e.g. with Ganache), but you can't simply up the gas limit on the public Ethereum network and testnets. The gas limit on Ropsten is currently around 8 million, and can only change very slightly depending on what the miners decide.